# How can I get more materials in Orna?

Tags: orna

To upgrade my equipment at a blacksmith shop, I need to get materials somehow. I found some bones, stone and wood on the map, but that almost nothing.

I know I can also get a little bit of materials from disassembling items but even with these two way materials seems very hard to find.

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to get more materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to places you would find those materials in real life to have increased drop. For example park (Real Life) could be marked as forest (In Game) and drop wood. Also some enemies drop needed materials, you can find more info on [Orna.Guide](https://orna.guide/items?show=283) for wood sources.